# Spring JDBC and Connection Object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm building an app using a proprietary api. To connect to the database I use a method that returns a Connection object and then on that connection I call the appropriate methods to run queries on the database for example....

```
Connection conn = JdbcServiceFactory.getInstance().getDefaultDatabase().getConnectionManager().getConnection();

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from test");
```

If I'm choosing to use Spring MVC 3 for my next project, what must I do to get the database connection setup? From what I've seen in the documentation, I have use the datasource tag in the container and pass a URL, username, and password. As shown, I currently don't have to do that to get the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day your proprietary API must access some database (available on some server), using some credentials. You just don't see this. In Spring you must first define some `DataSource`. Either use existing librariess like [dbcp](/questions/tagged/dbcp), [bonecp](/questions/tagged/bonecp) or [c3p0](/questions/tagged/c3p0) or take one provided by your application server via [jndi](/questions/tagged/jndi). As long as they implement `DataSource` interface, it doesn't matter what approach you choose. Too much to explain each one in detail.

Once you have `DataSource` bean set up, I **strongly recommend** using [`JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) which simplifies your JDBC code a lot, e.g:

```
 List<Map<String,Object>> res = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from test");
```

...and much more.

UPDATE: If you want to use your existing legacy API with modern frameworks expecting `DataSource` (pretty much all of them), implementing `DataSource` adapter is trivial (remaining methods can stay unimplemented, throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`):

```
public class LegacyDataSourceAdapter implements DataSource {
    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return JdbcServiceFactory.getInstance().getDefaultDatabase().getConnectionManager().getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        return getConnection();
    }

    //other methods are irrelevant
}
```

Now just create an instance of `LegacyDataSourceAdapter` (maybe as a Spring bean) and pass it to `JdbcTemplate`, Hibernate, myBatis...

---

BTW you have here some first class example of bad API design:

```
Connection conn = JdbcServiceFactory.
  getInstance().
  getDefaultDatabase().
  getConnectionManager().
  getConnection();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem is that the credentials are hidden from me and I'm not sure what's being used to get the connection. I was wondering if there was a way to use the existing libraries you mentioned without using credentials and just a connection object and it seems like there isn't. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Robert: actually, this is possible, see my update. You only need to wrap your legacy library with `DataSource` adapter.

Comment: You've helped me very much. Have a great day. Thanks.